# Can you create some kind of line follower robot with JUST a Raspberry Pi 3 as the computer?

Tags: pi-3

I wanted to attempt to build a line following robot using my Raspberry Pi 3. However, when I look up examples people have made, they all use some additional PCB or Arduino. Would I need anything extra, or can I control two DC motors just fine with a power source and and a Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: This is too broad and rather theoretical. It's certainly conceivable that there are DC motors that have built-in controllers compatible with RPi. Whether such motors are commercially available is another question. The whole point of tutorials is explaining how to build something you want with something you can easily get.

Comment: One of the other reasons for additional boards (motor drivers) or components is to protect the Pi and its GPIO pins from damage. A driver board is cheap insurance.  A driver board also allows for using motors that require more voltage/current than can be supplied by the Pi directly. You may want to consider this question when looking at other tutorials why did they use something (like a driver board).

Answer (score 2):

To drive a DC motor you need a motor driver board.  The Pi's GPIO can only supply a few milliamps (say 20) at 3.3V which will not drive a motor.

Look up L298N or L9110S based motor driver boards on eBay for examples.  Such boards typically drive two motors.

I'd suggest the L9110S if your motors are small as it is simpler to wire and understand.

You also need (probably) two light/dark sensors to track the line (assuming a black line on a white background or similar contrasting scheme).

If the sensors output 3V3 and are digital you could connect them direct to the Pi.

If they output 5V you would need to drop the output to a Pi GPIO safe 3V3 (typically using a pair of resistors to form a [voltage divider](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers)).

If they output an analogue voltage you would additionally need to buy an ADC such as the MCP3008 to convert the analogue output to a digital signal.

You will also need to buy jumper wires etc. to connect all the components.